# Failed to instantiate [org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormDataInput]: Specified class is an interface

Tags: java, spring, file, file-upload, resteasy

First time with resteasy. I'm trying to upload a file to rest, I referred to this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-resteasy/
but I'm getting an error. MultiPartFormDataInput doesn't seem to be accepted because it's an interface. Am I missing something?
Thanks.

Here's my endpoint:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8000")
@RequestMapping(value="upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public Response uploadFile(MultipartFormDataInput input) {

    String fileName = "";

    Map<String, List<InputPart>> uploadForm = input.getFormDataMap();
    List<InputPart> inputParts = uploadForm.get("file");

    for (InputPart inputPart : inputParts) {

     try {

        MultivaluedMap<String, String> header = inputPart.getHeaders();
        fileName = getFileName(header);

        //convert the uploaded file to inputstream
        InputStream inputStream = inputPart.getBody(InputStream.class,null);

        byte [] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

        //constructs upload file path
        fileName = UPLOADED_FILE_PATH + fileName;

        writeFile(bytes,fileName);

        System.out.println("Done");

      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

    }

    return Response.status(200)
        .entity("UPLOAD is called, Uploaded file name : " + fileName).build();

}
```

Here's my form:

```
<form action="rest/file/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <p>
    File to be uploaded : <input type="file" name="file" size="50"/>
   </p>

   <input type="submit" value="Upload It" />
</form>
```

Comment: Do you see that mkyong example using any Spring annotations? How do you expect Spring to know how to create this Resteasy object? One pattern that I'm starting to see more and more often with JAX-RS starters is the confusion that JAX-RS has any relation to Spring. You should be sure to keep a complete separation between the two when working with the "REST layer"

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out peeskillet.
Just for the sake of other newbies who will run into this problem, I followed this tutorial: http://www.journaldev.com/2573/spring-mvc-file-upload-example-tutorial-single-and-multiple-files